# Javascript loaded through jQuery Ajax does not throw expected exceptions in Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, exception, firebug

I have a Javascript functions which throw exceptions if something goes wrong. I have so used to this behavior, that one day it took me more than 20 minutes to find the error in code because the function did not threw exception, it just failed silently.

Try the following code in Firefox with Firebug plug-in.
Create a html page with a function:

```
function myfunc(key)
{ 
  alert('I started');
  if(!key)
     throw 'myfunc: Invalid arguments';
}
```

Then create a second html page with code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
myfunc(null);
alert('Exception was before me!');
</script>
```

and load this second html page from the first page with jQuery $.ajax function.

The code will be executed correctly, but you'll see no exceptions logged in the Firebug console.

If you run the same function  myfunc(null) right on the frst html page, you'll se iimediately a red line in Firebug saying:

```
uncaught exception: myfunc: Invalid arguments
```

But there is nothing logged out if it executed by jQuery (I guess, jQuery uses eval to run 
scripts after $.ajax).

Does this mean that jQuery itself catches exceptions and ignores them while evaluating Javascript? Is there any way I can tell jQuery to let my exceptions to go through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, this was a bug or a missing feature of jQuery 1.4. 
We upgraded to 1.6 and now exceptions are getting through even when the Javascript code is loaded and evaluated by jQuery $.ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, I think you actually want to return success, regardless of if it worked or not, and then a status code or an error message. This is because ajax doesn't return if there was a problem on the server. The status code allows the browser to know what happened instead of throwing the error on the server.

The reason this is, is because otherwise the server assumes that it was at fault, not the request, and throws the error there.

Comment: I just want jQuery to rethrow that 'myfunc: Invalid arguments' exception, but it does not happen. If I run myfunc(null) right from the first html page, Firebug shows a red line: "uncaught exception: myfunc: Invalid arguments" and I know what happened. But if it happens in a AJAXed script, the exception disappears somwehere.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the exception in FireBug you will need to use `console.log('Exception message');` rather than using `alert('Exception message');`